# JExcel Wrap Text Problem

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I have used JExcel api for generate Excel report.

I have issue in wrapped text.

It show me sqaure character instead of new line character.

```
WritableSheet s1 = workbook.createSheet("test", 0);
WritableCellFormat cellFormat = fonts.arial8ptNormal();
cellFormat.setWrap(true);

Label line = new Label(j, row, RiskUtility.replaceBlankIfNull(primaryIssueId).trim(), cellFormat);
s1.addCell(line);
```

it wil wrap text in cell but with special square character.

Answer (score 5):

From: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/faq/

Use "\012" or "\n". Also make sure to turn on cell wrapping with WritableCellFormat.setWrap(true) or the newline will show up as a square (unknown character).

Hope this can help =)